# What if $m<n$ in Preimage Theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-topology

$f:M\to N$ is a smooth map between manifolds of dimensions $m\geq n$. If $y\in N$ is a regular value, then the set $f^{-1}(y)$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $m-n$ or $\emptyset$.

What if $m<n$? My intuition tells me that $f^{-1}(y)$ is still a zero dimensional manifold but I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: There are no regular values in that case. The dimension of the target tangent space is larger than that of the domain tangent space, so the derivative can't possibly be surjective.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: Actually, in this case, a point $y$ in $N$ is a regular value of $f$ if and only if  $y$ does not belong to the image of $f$. Some people would say that in this case the preimage of $y$ has dimension $-1$ (as it is the empty set which has negative dimension if you use, say, inductive dimension as the notion of dimension).

Comment: @MoisheCohen: That makes sense as a convention.

Comment: In fact, I see now that it follows from looking at quantifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Grumpy Parsnip commented, the differential cannot be surjective for dimension reasons, so no point of $M$ is a regular value of $f$. Note that $f^{-1}(y)$ can look quite surprising in general; for instance, it can have infinitely many components (just look at the real line wrapped around $S^1$ via the morphism $\mathbb R^1 \to S^1$ and take the fiber of a point, which gives something like $\mathbb Z$). However, this is a case where the differential is surjective, so it is in no means a pathological situation. I thought it might shed some light on your question since I have an example of two connected manifolds and a fiber which has lots of components.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Dear Patrick: No, this does not help, since you seems to have discovered a counter example to Sard's Theorem (almost every point of the target space is a regular value). The right answer is that a point $y$ in $N$ is a regular value of $f$ if and only if  $y$ does not belong to the image of $f$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen : I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about, no offense. I certainly did not provide a counter example to anything, I just mentioned some property of the map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R/\mathbb Z \simeq S^1$.